# Map List<> with Automapper?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, automapper

I have two classes:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{

public string Name {get;set;}
public List<Order> Orders {get;set;}

}

public class OrderDTO
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Description {get;set;}
public decimal Cost{get;set;}
}
```

I am using AutoMapper for .NET 3.5 and currently doing the following in my Application_StartUp:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Order,OrderDTO>();
```

This is a simplified example as I named my DTO properties different than my entity properties, so I used ForMember, but I am unclear on how to map Orders to Customer:

I tried:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Orders, opt=> opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Orders));
```

but it does not find `src.Orders`.

If I do indeed need to have both `CreateMap` statements, does `AutoMapper` "automatically" link the objects `Customer` to `Orders`?

Comment: In the code you posted, CustomerDTO has an `orders` not an `Orders` property. Is that just a typo in the posting?  If it is as posted than that would be an issue, property names are case sensitive.

Comment: Also, if your map is 1 to 1, then you can just do `Mapper.Map(cust, custDTO)`

Comment: shouldn't the code also be `ListMOrdersDTO> Orders {get;set};`??

Comment: Can you post your `Ordem` and `Custumer` classes? Maybe the type of Orders properties isn't the same.

Comment: @JustinPihony - This is the confusing part to me. I understand the mapping cust to CustDTO, but how do I map OrdersDTO to the CustDTO?

Comment: Wait...why are you mapping them? That is not a very intuitive mapping even if the data is valid...keep maintainability in mind...but if they are 1 to 1, then you would just create a map

Comment: @JustinPihony A customer can have many orders and an many orders can be associated with 1 customer. Does that make sense?

Comment: So, your problem is mapping the internal components? Can you post a fuller example maybe? Based on the above code my answer should stand, so I think you are missing showing us something

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to tell AutoMapper about each mapping. It will not guess for you. So, if an `OrderDTO` should map to an `Order`, you must tell AutoMapper that. You must also specify the reverse relationship if that's needed as well (i.e. `Order` should map to `OrderDTO`).

In other words, for bi-directional mapping you would need:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderDTO, Order>();
```

As far as `Customer` goes, if both `Customer` and `CustomerDTO` have a property named `Orders`, you don't need to do anything else. As long as you've told AutoMapper to map between `Order` and `OrderDTO` and `Customer` and `CustomerDTO`, it will automatically map your `Order` when you map `Customer`.

Comment: Can you use the .ReverseMap() for that, @Chris Pratt

Comment: Nice. I actually didn't know about `ReverseMap`. AutoMapper is great, but the documentation leaves *much* to be desired. Still, bear in mind that `ReverseMap` only works with simple mappings like above. If you need to do custom stuff with `MapFrom`, etc. then you'll have to break out each direction.